# How to integrate Neo4j database, NestJS framework and GraphQL?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graphql, nestjs, resolver

I'm trying to integrate my REST API (NestJS) with new Neo4j database with GraphQL queries. Anybody succeed? Thanks in advance

EDIT 1: (I added my code)

```
import { Resolver } from "@nestjs/graphql";
import { Query, forwardRef, Inject, Logger } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Neo4jService } from "src/shared/neo4j/neoj4.service";
import { GraphModelService } from "./models/model.service";
import { Movie } from "src/graphql.schema";

@Resolver('Movie')
    export class GraphService {
    constructor(private readonly _neo4jService: Neo4jService) {}

    @Query()
    async getMovie() {
        console.log("hello");
        return neo4jgraphql(/*i don't know how get the query and params*/);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try showing us something you've attempted

Comment: @Gonzalo De Benito Cassadó

See if this may help.  https://medium.com/@faaizhussain/nestjs-graphql-neo4j-1e3e6e552a80

Comment: Check out https://DRIVINE.ORG. I haven't added GraphQL support yet, however I think that you will like it otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using a `NestInterceptor` to accomplish this:

```
@Injectable()
export class Neo4JGraphQLInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler<any>,
  ): Observable<any> | Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    return neo4jgraphql(
      ctx.getRoot(),
      ctx.getArgs(),
      ctx.getContext(),
      ctx.getInfo(),
    );
  }
}
```

To use it in your `Resolver`:

```
@Resolver('Movie')
@UseInterceptors(Neo4JGraphQLInterceptor)
export class MovieResolver {}
```

My `GraphQLModule` is configured like this:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      typePaths: ['./**/*.gql'],
      transformSchema: augmentSchema,
      context: {
        driver: neo4j.driver(
          'bolt://neo:7687',
          neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j', 'password1234'),
        ),
      },
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [...],
  providers: [..., MovieResolver, Neo4JGraphQLInterceptor],
})
```

Note the usage of `transformSchema: augmentSchema` to enable auto-generated mutations and queries ([GRANDStack: Schema Augmentation](https://grandstack.io/docs/neo4j-graphql-js.html#schema-augmentation))

Hope that helps a bit!

Comment: @GonzaloDeBenitoCassadó you didn't check accept this answer ..should I assume it didn't work for you?...did you find a better solution?

Comment: I changed the framework time ago, I think this is the better solution

Comment: @Christian Lutz .....can you clarify your use of the augmentSchema here?...I take it you have 'augmentSchema = makeAugmentedSchema(typeDefs) somewhere in your code...since you are not using 'definitions' I assume you are using 'definitionsFactory.generate' to generate the schema.ts file...I am getting an error 'unkown relation' when I do that.....it's rejecting the @ relation directives in the SDL file how did you compute 'augmentSchema'?

Comment: @MichaelE The `augmentSchema` function is the one from _neo4j-graphql-js_ https://grandstack.io/docs/neo4j-graphql-js-api.html#augmentschemaschema-config-graphqlschema. To make the `@relation` work I added `directive @relation(name: String, direction: String) on FIELD_DEFINITION` to my SDL file. Unfortunately I did not have the opportunity to work with graphql and nest since I posted this answer. So maybe things improved since then.

Comment: @ChristianLutz actually a new variable was introduced 'augmentTypeDefs' which now requires `const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: augmentTypeDefs(typeDefs),
 }); ` in order to get @relation and the neo4j directives working

Comment: @ChristianLutz I just got back to the question and I have a followup question for you. You indicated that you used GRANDStack to create the augmentedSchema...my question is...did you create a duplicated SDL type files to do this? typePaths: ['./**/*.gql'] would have created an inmemory schema for nest... so I would love to see the code used to create the augmentedSchema....if you don't mind ...thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have not worked on GraphQL, but I know there is an npm package([Neo4j-graphql-js](https://github.com/neo4j-graphql/neo4j-graphql-js)) to translate GraphQL queries into Cypher queries. It makes it easier to use GraphQL and Neo4j together.

Also, check [GRANDstack](https://grandstack.io/) it is a full-stack development integration for building Graph-based applications.

I suggest you to visit [Neo4j Community](https://community.neo4j.com/).

Comment: I'm reading all the documentation of this framework and I can't find the solution to my answer... Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

This is what works for me...not as elegant as I would like but it works; I want to have only one service/provider accessing my db not the service from each module even though that works also. So I am sticking with the Nest format of myModule->myResolver->myService-->Neo4jService. So Neo4jService is injected in all xService(s). I am using neo4jGraphql and augmentSchema and Cypher when necessary.

**Code**:

```
**appmodule.ts**
....
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import { v1 as neo4j } from 'neo4j-driver';
import { augmentTypeDefs, augmentSchema  } from 'neo4j-graphql-js';
import { Neo4jService } from './neo4j/neo4j.service';
import { MyModule } from './my/my.module';
import { MyResolver } from './my/my.resolver';
import { MyService } from './my/my.service';
....
import { typeDefs } from './generate-schema';  // SDL type file
...
const driver =  neo4j.driver('bolt://localhost:3000', neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j', 'neo4j'))

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: augmentTypeDefs(typeDefs),
 });
const augmentedSchema = augmentSchema(schema);   // Now we have an augmented schema

@Module({
  imports: [
    MyModule,

    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      schema: augmentedSchema,       
      context: {
      driver,
       },
     }),
    ],
  controllers: [],

  providers: [ Neo4jService,
               myResolver,
             ],
})
export class AppModule {}

**myResolver.ts**

import { Args, Mutation, Query, Resolver  } from '@nestjs/graphql';

import { MyService } from './my.service';

@Resolver('My')
export class MyResolver {

    constructor(
        private readonly myService: MyService) {}

      @Query()
      async getData(object, params, ctx, resolveInfo) {
       return await this.myService.getData(object, params, ctx, resolveInfo);
      }

     *//Notice I am just passing the graphql params, etc to the myService*

}

**myService.ts**

import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Neo4jService } from '../neo4j/neo4j.service';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    constructor(private neo4jService: Neo4jService) {}

    async getData(object, params, ctx, resolveInfo) {
        return await this.neo4jService.getData(object, params, ctx, resolveInfo);
   }

     *// Again I am just passing the graphql params, etc to the neo4jService*
 }
**neo4jService.ts**
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { neo4jgraphql } from 'neo4j-graphql-js';


@Injectable()
export class Neo4jService {

        getData(object, params, ctx, resolveInfo) {
              return neo4jgraphql(object, params, ctx, resolveInfo);
            }
     .....
     ......
}
```

So basically I postponed using neo4jgraphql until we arrive at neo4jService. Now all my DB calls are here.....as I said not elegant but it works.

Challenges: Graphql generate would not accept @relation...I found out that a change was made and now you need augmentTypeDefs.
...hope this helps
**EDIT**
Nestjs takes an awful long time to process the augmentSchema...so I would recommend skipping it..for now

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example i created for (NestJS + GraphQL + Neo4j). I hope if this may help!

[NestJS + GraphQL + Neo4j](https://medium.com/@faaizhussain/nestjs-graphql-neo4j-1e3e6e552a80)

Comment: With decorators it's pretty easy to read and implement! Thank you

Comment: thank you but its missing the most challenging issue: the custom directive from neo4j like @relationship