# Neo4j driver for Nestjs

Tags: neo4j, nestjs

I want to use neo4j in nest.js. Is there any way to use like Mongoose ODM in nestjs for neo4j ? For Mongoose, nest.js has following in their official documentation

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb

Is there any other solution for neo4j?

Comment: There are many OGM for Neo4j with Javascript. Check this https://libraries.io/search?keywords=neo4j&languages=&platforms=NPM

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Nestjs won't support Neo4j according to [this comment](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1309#issuecomment-441434865).

Also after a little search on the internet, these references can help you out I think:
- [Code snippet from the same thread as previous link](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1309#issuecomment-441396645)
- [Similar question to yours - plus GraphQl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53544876/how-to-integrate-neo4j-database-nestjs-framework-and-graphql)
- [Entire project based on NestJS, Neo4j, PostgreSQL and React](https://github.com/JKostov/neo4gig)

Hope this gives you some more insight about how to implement your module.